# How does one find the phonon frequencies for a 1D anharmonic interaction potential?

Tags: classical-mechanics, condensed-matter

Suppose there is a one-dimensional crystal with an anharmonic interaction potential between particles (e.g. $U = ax^2+bx^3$ where $x = d-a$ with $d$ as the distance between two particles and $a$ as the lattice spacing).

If I assume only nearest neighbour interactions exist, how can I find phonon frequencies?

Comment: With nonlinear interactions, the notion of phonons need to be reconsidered. In fact, as first studied by Fermi, Pasta and Ulam, solitonic excitations play an important role. See e.g. http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Fermi-Pasta-Ulam_nonlinear_lattice_oscillations

Comment: How large is the $b$ term? I disagree with @Meng Cheng. _All_ real phonon systems have an anharmonic potential; otherwise there'd be no scattering and thermal conductivity would be infinite. You typically use perturbation theory to deal with the non-linear term -- assuming that it's not too large. For example, se J. M. Ziman's book "Electrons and Phonons".

Comment: $b$ term is small. Your comment was helpful. Thanks.